# How do I initiate a WebRTC data channel?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, rtcdatachannel

I'm trying to create a WebRTC data channel between clients using web sockets.

I listed some ICE servers

```
var rtcsettings = {
  iceServers: [
    {url: "stun:stun.ekiga.net"},
    {url: "stun:stun.voipbuster.com"},
    {url: "stun:stun.1.google.com:19302"},
  ]   
};
```

Then there is a connect function that creates a channel and offer and sends it over the web socket.

```
function(them) {
  var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(rtcsettings);
  self.channel = pc.createDataChannel("gamelink");
  console.log(pc, self.channel);
  self.peerconnection = pc;
  pc.createOffer(function(offer) {
    pc.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer), function() {
      self.socket.send(JSON.stringify({
        "to": them,
        "uuid": uuid,
        "offer": offer,
      }));
    }, pc.close);
  }, pc.close);
}
```

Then on the other end there is a callback that adds the offer to its connection and sends a response.

It also sets a callback for when a data channel is added, but this never fires. What am I missing?

```
function (message){
  var offer = message.offer;
  var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(rtcsettings);
  pc.ondatachannel = function(ch) {
    self.channel = ch;
    console.log(self.channel);
  }
  console.log(pc);
  pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer), function() {
    pc.createAnswer(function(answer) {
      pc.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(answer), function() {
        self.socket.send(JSON.stringify({
          "to": message.uuid,
          "uuid": uuid,
          "answer": answer,
        }));
      }, pc.close);
    }, pc.close);
  }, pc.close);
  self.peerconnection = pc;
}
```

Then finally there is another callback on the initiator that adds the response descriptor to its connection.

```
function(message) {
  self.peerconnection.setRemoteDescription(
      new RTCSessionDescription(message.answer),
      function() { },
      self.peerconnection.close);
}
```

All of the code except the socket stuff and the data channel stuff is taken almost verbatim from the [MDN Basic Usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection) page.

I'm testing with Chrome on localhost, so firewalls should not be a problem.

After the exchange happens, both connections have a local and remote descriptor set. The data channel `readyState` is `connecting`. The PeerConnection's `iceConnectionState` is `new` and its `signalingState` is `stable`.

What's missing?

Answer (score 3):

You need to handle ICE candidates.

On **both** ends there needs to be a callback like this:

```
pc.onicecandidate = function(e) {
  if(e.candidate) {
    self.socket.send(JSON.stringify({
      "to": message.uuid,
      "uuid": uuid,
      "candidate": e.candidate,
    }));
  }
};
```

**and** a handler

```
callbacks["candidate"] = function(message) {
  console.log(message)
  self.peerconnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(message.candidate));
}
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Clue was `iceConnectionState` should have been `connected`.

Answer (score 0):

Add these settings to your RTCPeerConnection

```
var optionalRtpDataChannels = {
  optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]
};
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(rtcsetting, optionalRtpDataChannels);
```

Comment: Should not be needed anymore I don't think.

Comment: RtpDataChannels are nonstandard and will not be supported in Firefox.